# Need to return the properties of a Powershell cmdlet (get-wmiobject) in variables

Tags: powershell, wmi, windows-server

In Powershell I run a get-wmiobject on Win32_OperatingSystem, and it returns several properties through the select-object cmdlet.  How to I get the values loaded to variables instead of a list,since I need to further process them?  I tried several methods without avail.  If I can get this accomplished without the select-object cmdlet, that would also work.

```
get-wmiobject -namespace root\CIMV2 -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $servername | Select-Object SystemDirectory,caption,BuildNumber
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you know how to assign variables, so I'm not sure what the hang up is here. You would simply run the GWMI command as the value of a variable such as:

```
$Results = get-wmiobject -namespace root\CIMV2 -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $servername
```

Then reference the properties of the object you just created such as:

```
$Results.SystemDirectory
$Results.caption
$Results.BuildNumber
```